# AJAX requests with Mootools incorrectly sent as GET instead of POST

Tags: ajax, post, get, xmlhttprequest, mootools

I am running into a large amount of error reports associated with requests that should be coming in as POSTs, but instead are being requested as GETs. Most of the requests are made exclusively using JavaScript with the MooTools library (1.4.5).

The reports are also from a variety of different pages and browsers (IE 7 - 9 and Firefox 14 - 16). Some use the MooTools Request wrapper for XMLHttpRequest directly and others with the Element.send method.

I am guessing it is most likely a client-side issue of some sort, but I'm having trouble pin-pointing the problem(s), because I can not reproduce it locally. Any suggestions on common causes for this type of behavior?

One example is based on a basic form:

```
<div id="myParent">
    <form action="/DoSomething/Regular" class="validate" method="post">
        <textarea class="grow required" name="MyInfo"></textarea>
    </from>
</div>
```

And, the following JavaScript:

```
var myFormParent = $('myParent');
var myForm = myFormParent.getElement('form');

myForm.set('send', {
    url: '/DoSomething/Ajax',
    method: 'POST',
    noCache: true,
    onSuccess: doSuccessFunction
    onFailure: doFailureFunction
}).send();
```

**Update**

It looks like proxy servers are behind some of these odd requests, specifically [WildBlue](http://www.wildblue.com/customers/optimizer) Optimizer. Is there anything that could be making these proxy servers continually attempt to access these files as a GET request, when all of the site's normal users correctly perform POST requests.

Comment: nothing wrong with that code. http://jsfiddle.net/b9wtJ/ - arrives as POST

Comment: I narrowed down one subset of users who are all using WildBlue high speed internet, [link](http://www.wildblue.com/customers/optimizer). They appear to have some sort of _Optimizer_, that uses a proxy sever, and it is causing these odd requests.

Comment: I find it funny that the WildBlue site doesn't recommend installing their optimizer software on newer modems. At any rate -- have you tried using `.post()` instead of `.send()`? (You don't have to specify a method that way).